# PostCSS with .css file not rendering the nested classes nor pseudo classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css, storybook, postcss, nrwl-nx

tw-imports.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nrwl/angular/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  darkMode: 'media',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcsss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'postcss-import',
    'tailwindcss',
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
    'postcss-nested',
    'postcss-custom-properties',
    'autoprefixer',
    [
     'postcss-preset-env',
     {
         autoprefixer: {
             flexbox: 'no-2009',
         },
         stage: 3,
         features: {
             'custom-properties': true,
             'nesting-rules': true,
         },
     },
    ],
  ],
}
```

css

```
.button {
  @apply rounded text-slate-500 ring-slate-900/5 shadow p-3 ring-2;

  &:hover {
    --mainColor: #b3a5c0;
    color: var(--mainColor);
  }
}
```

.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  // uncomment the property below if you want to apply some webpack config globally
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need that should apply to all storybook configs

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

result
[image]

Comment: Did you create main.css file and added these directives at the top tailwind base; tailwind components; tailwind utilities; ? Check step 4 in the official docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

Comment: @Aadesh yes, sorry I will add it, but I would like to use postcss for custom classes and tailwind together. Inside Storybook too,

Comment: In `postcsss.config.js` have you tried changing the order? In my config I always run the nested plugin before `tailwindcss`.

Comment: @stickyuser can you share an example in your git or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `postcss.config.js` example from my most recent project. I am using `tailwindcss/nesting` which still wraps `postcss-nested` as explained here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "tailwindcss/nesting": {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    cssnano: {
      preset: "default",
      autoprefixer: { add: false },
    },
  },
}
```

I had a similar problem as you a while back, and package versions were important, so here is my `package.json`.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-custom-media": "^7.0.8",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

This is TailwindCSS v3, and it looks like you may be using v2, but hopefully it is still useful.

Comment: I have replaced mine and seems like I still unable to render it. Can you show your css and storybook configs?

Comment: I am not familiar with storybook config, so if you think that is the root of the issue I don't think I can help any further sorry.